# In Eclipse, how do I detect where in the code .project is getting updated?

Tags: eclipse

I'm experiencing a problem where somewhere in the an Eclipse Plugin a class is modifying the .project file, but I'm unable to determine which code/class it is.

I'm on a Windows XP machine.  Is there a way I can set a breakpoint or setup some sort of a listener so I can see where in the code the .project file is being modified by?  (ideally by setting a breakpoint somewhere so I could see the stack where it is occurring).

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?Which type of project you are creating c, c++ or Java?

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion but maybe you've already tried this: set your .project as read-only before firing eclipse, so that you can have at least an idea about the plugin that modify your .project